# Screen not updated after calling FutureBuilder again

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, dart-async

I have a screen that loads shopping cart items in a ListView.builder:

```
Expanded(
                    child: RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: refresh,
                        child: Container(
                          child: FutureBuilder(
                            future: loadData(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {

      List<dynamic>? filteredList = snapshot.data as List;
...
```

The data are loaded using the function `loadData()`

```
 Future<List<LineaCesta>> loadData() async {
    await fetchLineasCesta(idCesta);
    return fetchLineasCesta(idCesta);
  }
```

Then, inside the item card, there are some buttons to add or remove product quantity.

Here you have the case for adding a new one:

```
onPressed:  () async {
//añadir uno maas
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
idCesta = prefs.getString("cesta_id")!;
checkExistenciaCestaPoner( idCesta!,lineaCesta.producto,lineaCesta.precio,context); 
print(  "refrescando despues de añadir item"); 
   });
  });
}
```

Then there are called other functions that at the end are calling the function `loadData()` again.

The issue is that all made changes are not updated after calling loadData.

I need to leave the screen and load it again to get all data updated.

EDIT:

```
Future<List<LineaCesta>> fetchLineasCesta(String cesta) async {


  String url = Constantes().URLProyecto+Constantes().APICarpeta+"get_lineas_cesta.php?cesta="+cesta;
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  return lineaCestaFromJson(response.body);

}
```

Comment: where do you update the ui to see the changes?

Comment: @eamirho3ein,I have been including setState at the end of  every function , but not working

Comment: could you include fetchLineasCesta? and say way are you calling it twice in loadData?

Comment: @eamirho3ein, I am not calling it twice, first I am calling it with the await and then I am returning it to the FutureBuilder. If there is another way to do it better, please tell me. I will include fetchLineasCesta in my question as Edit.

Comment: also in your example , you are add the new one into SharedPreferences but you try to get it from api? how that possible?

Comment: @eamirho3ein, you are talking about different  subjects. Every time the user increases or decreases the quantity of a product, the info is uploaded to the server and updated to sharedPreferences and provider, but I need to leave the screen and enter again to get the changes in the listview

Comment: could you update the question and add the full code of onPressed part?to see what is going on there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you like to refresh the FutureBuilder, reassing the future variable. For this I will prefer creating a separate variable for FutureBuilder's `future`.

```dart
 late Future<List<LineaCesta>> loadDateFuture = loadData();
```

And use

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<LineaCesta>>(
  future: loadDateFuture,
```

Now to update, reassign the  `loadDateFuture`

```dart
loadDateFuture = loadData(); // like this
```

You can check 
[Randal L. Schwartz's video](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg)

Comment: Also `Future<List<LineaCesta>> loadData() async =>await fetchLineasCesta(idCesta);` no need to call two times